# Changing image color

Tags: php, html, css, html5-canvas, gd

I have learnt `img_filter_colorize()` of php little bit. I want to give user a option to choose color for an image. Example is [here](http://www.dezignwithaz.com/fairy-tree-wall-decals-p-1251.html)

My code is:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatefrompng('flower.png');
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, 255);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 255, 0, 0);
imagepng($im, 'flower1.png');
?>
```

This code is creating a new image with red color but here I don't want to create an image, only display in screen.

For example if user selects red button image changes to red and so on.

Is this achievable?
Is there any other way to do it (javascript, canvas or any other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave out the second filename parameter of the `imagepng()` call it will just output the bytes of the image and it won't be saved to a file, so you can use this script's url inside an `<img src="">` and it should be rendered fine.

**However** that would be really wasteful with your server resources because every time the image gets downloaded the calculations have to run again, if you have a fix palette it's probably better to pre-generate the images or at least cache the generated versions.

For the user facing part, you probably want to use javascript to change the DOM inside the browser when the user clicks on the "red" button. Something along the lines of this:

```
<img src="the_default_color.png" id="image">
<button id="make_it_red">Make it red</button>
<script>
document.getElementById('make_it_red').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('image').src = 'path_to_your_image_generator_php_script.php';
};
</script>
```

You might want to make the php script parameterized with rgb values, so you can use it for every color.

Answer (score 0):

`imagepng` will output png file content directly if you dont use `filename` parameter like :

```
imagepng($im);
```

and than, you can request the image like

```
<img src="http://your-shost/yourimagescript.php" />
```

Answer (score 0):

create only a view of the photo (without creating a new flower1.jpg)

```
<?php
echo '<img src="photo.php" height="42" width="42">';
?>
```

and in a new file: photo.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatefrompng('flower.png');
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, 255);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 255,0, 0);
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```